# The first association?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find a word which would describe the first association made when exposed to a given concept. For example, Kleenex and Paris might be the first associations to tissue or France. It would be a word which describes the fact that Kleenex and Paris are strongly present in the collective consciousness, and as such are likely to be naturally associated to related concepts/domains by most people.

Comment: The expression 'B is synonymous with A' is frequently used to mean 'When one has a thought about B, it almost always triggers a thought about A'.

Comment: The word *association* may be replaced by "correlation", "connectedness" or "inter-relationship". But, you still need an adjective to specify how strong is the relation: i.e. "first", "strong", "high", "natural", "immediate", etc.

Comment: "The icon" or "The primary icon" might work depending on the particular context.

Answer (score 1):

The word 'exemplar' seems to be closely related to the word you look for.

https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikisaurus:exemplar

Sense: something typical or representative of a class

Answer (score 1):

Let me propose:

- [epitome](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/epitome): a person or thing that is typical of or possesses to a high degree the features of a whole class,
- [embodiment](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/embodiment): a person, being, or thing embodying a spirit, principle, abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

**"Instinct" (n.)**

> a largely inheritable and unalterable tendency of an organism to make a complex and specific response to environmental stimuli without involving reason
>
> Merriam-Webster

The keywords I'm taking from your question are: "likely to be naturally associated to related concepts/domains by most people."

My take-away is that you want a word that describes the statistical mode of the association question. The question being a stimuli and the association being the response. Because you are looking for the most common answer, you could say that the collective unconscious, or "instinct" is to relate Kleenex given the stimuli "tissue" (a proprietary eponym as Cindy mentions).

Answer (score -1):

Generic trademarks leads to eponym, the thing something is named for. Thinking of cognitive biases and heuristics leads to availability, representativeness, and anchoring as possible words, from availability heuristic, representativeness heuristic, and anchoring.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_trademark

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Availability_heuristic